# How to fix Fabric Js and to RemoveColor issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js and to remove a white background I used the RemoveColor Filter. it working fine it the image is size is less then 2000px if the image size is large like 2500px the edges are cut of.

[Image less then 2000px remove white working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOXII.png)

[Image greater than 2000px edge cut of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5R7o.png)

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56vM4.png)

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('resized_245001682.png', function(oImg) {
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveColor({
      color:"#fff",
      threshold: 40,
      distance: 0.1
    });
    oImg.applyFilters();
    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is occur because of the default textureSize is 2048, Use

```
fabric.textureSize = 5000;
```

Comment: This solution is correct. One caveat is that some hardware and browsers will struggle when setting a texturesize that is too large. See http://fabricjs.com/fabric-filters for more info.